# How does namespace works in ant build file?

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib, java-compiler-api

I'm trying to use ant-contrib and I notice sometime it is used specifying the ac: namespace and sometimes not.

When should I use the namespace and why?

Answer (score 1):

Ant-contrib is packaged as an [antlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html). This is the more modern way to distribute ANT extensions.